# how to understand the following empty if statement in python?

Tags: python

I read the following Python code from a book, which should be very easy to understand. I was just wondering, what is the purpose of the following empty if statement:

```
if currentLabel not in labelCounts.keys():
labelCounts[currentLabel] = 0
labelCounts[currentLabel] += 1
```

The full code is:

```
from math import log
def calcShannonEnt(dataSet):
    numEntries = len(dataSet)
    labelCounts = {}
    for featVec in dataSet:
        currentLabel = featVec[-1]
        if currentLabel not in labelCounts.keys():
        labelCounts[currentLabel] = 0
        labelCounts[currentLabel] += 1
    shannonEnt = 0.0
    for key in labelCounts:
        prob = float(labelCounts[key])/numEntries
        shannonEnt -= prob * log(prob,2)
    return shannonEnt
```

Comment: If that's _exactly_ how it appears in the book, the purpose is a syntax error and you should read a different book.

Comment: There is no empty `if` in python that's a SyntaxError

Comment: Are you sure your indenting is right?  It seems like the `labelCounts[currentLabel] =0 ` should be indented.  If it's absolutely like that in the book I'd bet it's a typo

Comment: If you named the book, we could look for errata by the publisher, allowing a better answer. And, as an extra bonus, we could avoid recommending it to anyone else. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I would go further: this question and its answers have absolutely no value at all without the name of the book. As it is, it's basically "is there supposed to be an obvious bug here?", "no, it should be corrected."

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I agree, which is why I'm weighing in on the close vote. Perhaps you might do likewise?

Comment: Agreed - a typo is a typo, regardless of who the author is. If the book's title is added we can always retract/reopen. ntough, please add the book's title.

Comment: wow. Can not believe that there are so many answers so quickly. The book is a very traditional book about machine learning. I copied the code from the book.

Comment: Ugh, that `if` is quite inefficient as it builds a list of the keys and then does a linear search instead of doing a simple O(1) lookup of the key in the dictionary. `collections.defaultdict` could also be used to simplify the code by eliminating the `if` altogether. Or even better: `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if currentLabel not in labelCounts.keys():
labelCounts[currentLabel] = 0
labelCounts[currentLabel] += 1
```

is error. It's *probably* badly indented and should be:

```
if currentLabel not in labelCounts.keys():
    labelCounts[currentLabel] = 0
labelCounts[currentLabel] += 1
```

You can't have "empty" `if` in Python. Altrough you can have this:

```
if something:
    pass
```

Which effectively does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you need an indent, your code should be generating the key if it doesn't exist then it increments a counter on that key, += should not be indented to account for keys that already exist and your newly created key:

```
if currentLabel not in labelCounts.keys():
  labelCounts[currentLabel] = 0
labelCounts[currentLabel] += 1
```

another way of putting it:

```
if currentLabel not in labelCounts.keys():
  labelCounts[currentLabel] = 1
else:
  labelCounts[currentLabel] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the second line is supposed to be indented, like so:

```
if currentLabel not in labelCounts.keys():
    labelCounts[currentLabel] = 0
labelCounts[currentLabel] += 1
```

This would be done to avoid throwing an error if the dict `labelCounts` does not contain a key with the value of `currentLabel`